# How to get all the jobs via curl command for sauce labs api?

Tags: curl, saucelabs

I am trying to retrieve all the jobs in saucelabs, currently i am running curl on the api link https://api.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/v1/rdc/jobs/, but only a handful of results are being shown instead of all. Is there a way to show all?

My current command is: curl -u "user:key" -X GET "https://api.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/v1/rdc/jobs/"

if anyone knows how to make all the results show, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are at least getting some data back. You may need to increase the `limit` param, per our docs: https://docs.saucelabs.com/dev/api/rdc/

For example

```
https://api.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/v1/rdc/jobs/?limit=800
```

[image: sauce labs jobs RDC docs]

Comment: Even with the `limit` parameter, you should use the `offset` to only grab a certain number at a time; I suggest groups of 100.